# how can i find out what email is linked to my steam account

Tags: steam, technical-issues, pc

the steam guard email isn't going to any of the emails that I have and I don't know what email address it is going to

Comment: You can check your email from "Account details" in the Steam client (top right corner), but I don't think you can find this email address before you are logged in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to reset/change my Steam email without being logged on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220064/is-there-a-way-to-reset-change-my-steam-email-without-being-logged-on)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Steam Guard FAQ page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4020-ALZM-5519#email), the email should be sent to whatever email you have associated with your Steam Account:

> Make sure that you are watching the inbox for the email address associated with your Steam account.

Additional [Source](https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithSteamGuardCode):

> Steam Guard emails are sent to the last email address registered for your Steam account.
>
> If you are not receiving Steam Guard emails:
>
> - Verify that you are accessing the email address registered to your Steam account
> - Check your email spam filter to ensure the message was not flagged as spam
> - Add support@steampowered.com and noreply@steampowered.com to your contacts or trusted senders list within your email client
> - Wait up to 30 minutes for the email to be delivered. Even though Steam instantly sends the Steam Guard code email, you may encounter a delay with some email providers depending on their server load and processing times. If you haven't received your code after thirty minutes, please attempt to log in again to receive a new Steam Guard code.

It also recommends to check your spam email box.  It's always a good idea to do this for any kind of email you are expecting from a known entity.

To check what email you have associated to your account, go to the Steam Settings under the Account tab and there is a contact email on this form that should be it (blacked out in image).  In the top right is a View Account Details button, to which it also shows more contact info about your account, and the same email.

[image: Accounts Tab]

[image: Account Details]

It appears you can change your email, but you'll likely have to jump through a bunch of security hoops to do so.

If you aren't able to get to your Account Details, you can try [this Steam help site](https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithLoginInfo?reset=2&issueid=409) where you can enter in your account name, an email address, or phone number, and it will try to find your account to which you can have it send an email to the email associated to said account, or if you no longer have access to that email, you can select that option and fill out some more information (and probably have to wait quite a while).

[image: no access to email]